# SQLite Android . unable to open database file

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I found a lot of question about this problem, but i can't fix it.
I have a sqlite db in assets folder:

```
assets/data/data/{package_name}/databases/mydb.db
```

I can open database and read data before change one table structure. I try to uninstall the app and reinstall again, but i get the same exception.

What can i do now?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

```
// The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/{mypagackename}/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "mydb.db";
```

Open database (Before change table structure, adding some fields, it doesn't work)

```
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}
```

Comment: What exception? What code you are trying?

Comment: You are modifying the table structure within program or before and save new configuration to the assets folder?

Comment: I'm modifying table structure with http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/files/latest/download I save the file and replace it in assets folder. what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please consider using `SQLiteAssetHelper` as a debugged solution for packaging a database with your app and unpacking it on first use: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: No it's not gonna work this way, db should be in internal device memory. data/data/your.package.name/your.db not in assets.

Comment: Ok, Maxim you are right. I have my db in asset folder, but, firts it's necesary to check if database exists at the internal device memory. If don't exists, copy database and now are working. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, you can't use database right from the assets, you have to copy it over into internal data storage first and open it from there

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hard coded `DB_PATH` (no longer work in JB), I would recommend always go with Android inbuilt API method,

```
mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
```