# How to insert Sqlite database into android ?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a dump database. I just wanted to insert the database into my application and retrive it. Please help me. I am new to android .. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where your database is and where you want to copy ?

Comment: Please ask only full question with your code..

Comment: I am doing a vocabulary application. It contains nearly 8000 records. So how can i insert into the android application and retrive it.. Is there any code or procedure for that ? Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void checkDB() throws Exception {
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase dbe = SQLiteDatabase
                .openDatabase(
                        "/data/data/yourpackagename/databases/yourfilename.sqlite",
                        null, 0);
        Log.d("opendb", "EXIST");
        dbe.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        AssetManager am = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(
                "/data/data/yourpackagename/databases/yourfilename.sqlite");
        byte[] b = new byte[100];

        int r;
        InputStream is = am.open("yourfilename.sqlite");
        while ((r = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, r);
        }
        Log.i("DATABASE_HELPER", "Copying the database ");
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }

}
```

Please Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801119/how-to-access-sqlite-database-in-the-asset-folder-of-an-android-project)

[Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Comment: OMG! I already tried with that link u provided but didn't changed the database Field id to "_id". Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this way. Create CSV file of your values. Insert it into the Assets folder.

Than on first run read file and insert it into the SQLite database on your phone.

I can  post code examples later.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There's a library for that, I used it once, too.

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper