# ormlite - cannot open file at line...: /data/data/package_name/databases/cashdata-journal

Tags: android, database, sqlite, ormlite

I work with ormlite database and sometimes while application is running I receive :

```
 09-16 19:26:41.726: E/SQLiteLog(13495): (14) cannot open file at line 30176 of [00bb9c9ce4]
09-16 19:26:41.726: E/SQLiteLog(13495): (14) os_unix.c:30176: (24) open(/data/data/com.tempcontacts/databases/cashdata-journal) - 
09-16 19:26:41.726: E/SQLiteLog(13495): (14) cannot open file at line 30176 of [00bb9c9ce4]
09-16 19:26:41.726: E/SQLiteLog(13495): (14) os_unix.c:30176: (24) open(/data/data/com.tempcontacts/databases/cashdata-journal) - 
09-16 19:26:41.726: E/SQLiteLog(13495): (14) statement aborts at 15: [SELECT * FROM `reminders`] unable to open database file
09-16 19:26:41.726: E/SQLiteQuery(13495): exception: unable to open database file (code 14); query: SELECT * FROM `reminders`
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495): java.sql.SQLException: Problems executing Android query: SELECT * FROM `reminders` 
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.getCursor(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:158)
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.runQuery(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:57)
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.<init>(SelectIterator.java:55)
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:206)
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:155)
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.queryForAll(StatementExecutor.java:113)
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryForAll(BaseDaoImpl.java:237)
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at com.library.FrequentlyUsedMethods.getDisplayReminders(FrequentlyUsedMethods.java:225)
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at com.tempcontacts.CalendarHoursViewActivity$GridCellAdapter.getView(CalendarHoursViewActivity.java:386)
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1341)
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:341)
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:283)
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:417)
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1229)
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
09-16 19:26:41.726: W/System.err(13495):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
09-16 19:26:41.736: W/System.err(13495):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
09-16 19:26:41.736: W/System.err(13495):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
09-16 19:26:41.736: W/System.err(13495):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
```

This method causes this problem:

```
public ArrayList<ReminderItem> getDisplayReminders(Context context)
    {   
        ArrayList<ReminderItem> contactsList = null;
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getContext().getApplicationContext());
         try {
             db.getWritableDatabase();
            Dao<ReminderItem,Integer> daoSubject = db.getReminderDao();
            contactsList = (ArrayList<ReminderItem>) daoSubject.queryForAll();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return contactsList;

    }
```

when I try to get ArrayList of the objects from the database.

Gray, please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite Android . unable to open database file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671129/sqlite-android-unable-to-open-database-file)

Comment: I don't think this is an ORMLite issue.  Maybe a dupe?

Comment: @Gray - no, while the symptoms are similar it is not a duplicate as the fundamental issue is not the same and the solution would not apply.  It's pretty much only clear when you read the accepted answer, but the problem in that question is with something stored in assets, while the path here is to the actual database location in private storage.

Comment: Haven't used ormlite but single `db.getWritableDatabase()` looks suspicious - you don't store the result anywhere and there's no release of the "writable database" anywhere. Now opening the database journal file fails, possibly because it's already open by another "writable database" instance and the operating system file level locking kicks in.

Comment: I added db.getWritableDatabase() after the problem occured. So I got the same without it.